# Alternative to deprecated WebMvcConfigurerAdapter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("my.projects")

    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter 
    {
        @Override
        public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            converters.add(new CsvHttpMessageConverter<>());
        }
        public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.favorPathExtension(true).
favorParameter(true).
parameterName("mediaType").ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
            .useJaf(false).defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                    .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).mediaType("csv", new MediaType("text", "csv"));
        }
    }
```

The above wont work without extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` which is deprecated. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) suggests

> **Deprecated.**
>   as of 5.0 `WebMvcConfigurer` has default methods (made possible by a Java 8 baseline) and can be implemented directly without the need for this adapter

and instead have your `@Configuration` class implement [`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html)

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("my.projects")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new CsvHttpMessageConverter<>());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true).favorParameter(true).parameterName("mediaType").ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
                .useJaf(false).defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("csv", new MediaType("text", "csv"));
    }
}
```